# How to integrate a videocall API with Wordpress?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I am having some problem in understand how to integrate a videocall API with a Wordpress site.

I am developing a website which has a "meeting room", this site is built using Wordpress. I am trying to use some videocalls APIs, but couldn't understand the steps in order to integrate with de Worpress. Do I have to build a plugin?

I know some existing plugins for videocall, but they do not have the features I need, therefore I found some videocalls APIs that have the features I need. I also know how to embbed a videocall using iframe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to write your own video communication plugin using WebRTC technology, pay attention to:

1. select signaling for videochat
2. creating of Turn server
3. try this example: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webrtc2/